# In the connectionStrings tag, write server name where you have executed the angular scripts as data source and save it

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, httpclient, angular-services

I am learning angular programming and was going through the topic 'services' and how to fetch data using HttpClient. in there there was this line mentioned which i didnt understand. the line says 'In the connectionStrings tag, **write server name where you have executed the angular scripts** as data source and save it'. What does it mean to write server name where you have executed angular script? I am using visual studio code to run the program and the output/webpage is generated on chrome browser. the port i am using is localhost:4200. Till now i didnt use any database server to fetch data, everything was hard coded. what should i do to proceed further?

web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="QuickKartDBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/QuickKartModel.csdl|res://*/QuickKartModel.ssdl|res://*/QuickKartModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=QuickKartDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
        preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>

    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,Origin,Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That line does not make sense. Can your show me where I can find it in context?

Comment: the line was suggesting me to paste the localhost name in the connection string tag, which i was using to run the script on the browser. But the doubt that remains still is in connectionString="....." should i remove whatever is there between the quotes and paste the localhost name or should i paste the localhost name after the data source mentioned between connectionString quotes?

Comment: Honestly, I think you need to find a better class or instructor. It is just not clear what he means by _"In the connectionStrings tag, write server name where you have executed the angular scripts as data source and save it"_. The grammar is awful, but what makes it borderline nonsensical is that none of the nouns in that "sentence" are even related to each other.